# Remotely Ubuntu management & monitoring?

Tags: vpn, remote, monitoring

I have a bunch of PC's running ubuntu and have them configured on that way that I can connect via VPN with bunch of ports. I have issues monitoring them as /var/ partitions, RAM "magically" missing and so on. So can you recommend some software that can do monitoring on them and on same time if possible let me connect on them with some kind of link like sshc:// or simmilar.

Comment: Look into Nagios?

Comment: I never made it to connect on my VPN system, it just doesnt want to work with my ports :S ... Also tried Observium but there is no option to connect on pc from it

Answer (score 0):

*Regarding possible server monitoring solutions*

- Nagios - https://www.nagios.org/
- Incinga - https://www.icinga.org/
- Munin - http://munin-monitoring.org/
- Spiceworks - http://www.spiceworks.com/
- Zabbix - http://www.zabbix.com/
- Cacti - http://www.cacti.net/
- Monit - https://mmonit.com/monit/

I do use nagios a lot, it needs some time to get started but is worth the time if you care about monitoring.